# How can I pass a shared_pointer to a constructor correctly?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I am facing a problem with my c++ code. After the Track constructor has finished I get "SIGABRT (Aborted) corrupted size vs. prev_size" (I think when Ts goes out of scope).

How do I pass this vector to the member objects correctly without it causing problems when going out of scope? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Track::Track(std::vector<double> X, std::vector<double> Y){

    cumulativeLengths = {0.0};

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> Ts = arange<double>(0, X.size());

    xSpline = Spline(*Ts, X);
    ySpline = Spline(*Ts, Y);

}

class Spline {

public:
    Spline();
    Spline(std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& y);

    std::vector<double> x;
    std::vector<double> y;
};

Spline::Spline(std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& y): x(x), y(y) {

    updateSpline();

}

template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> arange(T start, T stop, T step) {

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> values = std::make_shared<std::vector<T>>();
    values->resize(std::ceil(stop-start/step));

    auto it =  values->begin();

    for (T value = start; value < stop; value += step)
        *it = value;
        it++;
    return values;
}
```

Comment: You should almost *never* use pointers to containers. What is the reason you do it here?

Comment: Also note that you're *not* passing the shared pointer to your constructor. You dereference the pointer and pass a reference to the actual object. Then you store a *copy* of the vector. No sharing at all here.

Comment: Is `it++;` supposed to be outside the for loop?  Based on its indentation, it appears that it was intended to be part of the loop.  May need curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

The *probable* reason is that you go out of bounds of your vector.

You create a vector with `std::ceil(stop-(start/step))` (extra parentheses added to highlight the operator precedence) number of elements, but loop over `(stop - start) / step` element in the loop afterwards.